# Can we support different password hashing algorithm in duende identity server

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, password-protection, duende-identity-server, duende

Currently I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher` for doing the password hash when I add an user to the system and it works well. But in order to change that methodology and use a customized password hashing algorithm what should I do in duende identity server ?

Is there any way to customize password hashing algorithm in duende identity server

Answer (score 0):

This concern is outside of the scope of Duende (it's part of core ASP.Net now) but it certainly is possible to implement a different algo by creating and registering your own `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` implementation.

I'd strongly recommend not rolling your own though and the PBKDF2 scheme used by ASP.Net Identity is still considered "good".

Did you have a particular alternative in mind?